# HugeInt error. Debug Assertion Failed

Tags: c++

I'm creating a HugeInt class. My main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HugeInt hi1("123");
    HugeInt hi2("456");

    std::cout << hi1 + hi2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and my HugeInt class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define SIZE 32

class HugeInt
{
    friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const HugeInt &);

public:
    HugeInt();
    HugeInt(const char *);
    ~HugeInt();

    HugeInt operator+(const HugeInt &) const;
private:
    int * buffer;
    int size;
};
```

and his methods:

```
HugeInt::HugeInt()
{
    size = SIZE;
    buffer = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        buffer[i] = 0;
    }
}

HugeInt::HugeInt(const char * hugeNumber)
{
    size = strlen(hugeNumber);
    buffer = new int[size];

    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        buffer[i] = hugeNumber[i] - '0';
    }
}

HugeInt::~HugeInt()
{
    delete[] buffer;
}

HugeInt HugeInt::operator+(const HugeInt & operand) const
{
    HugeInt temp;

    int carry = 0;

    if (size >= operand.size)
        temp.size = size;
    else
        temp.size = operand.size;

    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size; i++) {
        temp.buffer[i] = buffer[i] + operand.buffer[i] + carry;

        if (temp.buffer[i] > 9) {
            temp.buffer[i] %= 10;
            carry = 1;
        }
        else {
            carry = 0;
        }
    }

    return temp;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & output, const HugeInt & complex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < complex.size; i++)
        output << complex.buffer[i];
    return output;
};
```

Everything compiles fine. But console displays "-17891602-17891602-17891602" and then an error "Debug Assertation fail! .... Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)".

The problem is in "return temp" when we redefine operator+(). What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fair few bugs in this code

Your main issue is you're returning a class by value (at the end of `operator+`) *without* defining a copy constructor for it. You should read up on the *Rule of 3* (or its newer incantations *Rule of 5* or even the *Rule of 0*).

Basically, as you don't do a deep copy (the default copy constructor which is provided for you as you didn't define one does a shallow copy), both your original `temp` and the copy of that you actually return both point to the same `buffer`. When the destructor of `temp` runs at the end of the function (assuming no NRVO happens) it deletes the said buffer even though the copy you returned still points to it.

You can fix this by adding a correct *copy constructor* (and so fulfil the rule of 3) or a better fix would be to use a `std::vector<int>` instead of a manually managed buffer and so wouldn't need either a copy-constructor or a destructor (*Rule of Zero*).

Just looking through your code there's a few more issues. In your add function you fiddle with the `size` member of the `temp` instance without actually changing the buffer. If you happen to set `size` to bigger than the allocated buffer then you'll write off the end of valid memory triggering *undefined behavoir*.

Useful links for [Rule of 3/5/0](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)